# How can I connect my local VSCode to a remote Windows Server running 2016 Datacenter on it for remote development?

Tags: visual-studio-code, remote-debugging, windows-server, windows-server-2016, vscode-debugger

I tried using the **remote development extension** in marketplace on VSCode and it **worked while connecting to the linux(ubuntu) server**, **but not when I tried connecting to the windows server**.
I have the **rdp file** of the server, I searched the internet on how to edit the config file for the connection for windows server remotely but ended up with only solutions for connecting to ubuntu server.

Can someone please share materials or guide me as to how I can set it up?

My main purpose is to debug the code files on the server locally in real time.